# chose colors for scale_colour_colorblind() in ggthemes

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-blindness, ggthemes

I would like to chose specific colors of the `colorblind_pal()` from `ggthemes`

This works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                                     colour = factor(gear))) + facet_wrap(~am)
p + theme_igray() + scale_colour_colorblind()
```

Now I would like to chose specific colors of the `colorblind_pal()` for my plot. How can I chose them?

I tried following with no success:

```
my_palette <- palette(c("#000000","#F0E442","#D55E00"))
p + theme_igray() + scale_colour_colorblind(my_palette)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `scale_color_manual` in order to manually specify the colors to use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

p <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = factor(gear))) +
  facet_wrap(~am) +
  theme_igray() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000","#F0E442","#D55E00"))
p
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the colors, you can just use `scale_color_manual`:

```
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
COLS=colorblind_pal()(8)

COLS = COLS[c(1,5,7)]

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                                     colour = factor(gear))) + facet_wrap(~am)
p + theme_igray() + scale_colour_manual(values=COLS))
```

[image]